# Is the size of log file effecting performance of the database? How to Shrink log file?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just checked my logfile and its almost 45GB.
I have two questions:

Is it effecting performance of database in general?
How to shrink it with SQL query? (please give me an example)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Shrinking your Transaction Log file under normal circumstances should not be necessary.**

It oftens means you are in FULL Recovery Mode and not regular performing Transaction Log backups.

The size of the Log file will not affect performance per se. BUT Virtual Log File (VLF) fragmentation can (and often will) have very adverse effects on performance.

Please see: [Transaction Log VLFs - too many or too few?](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Transaction-Log-VLFs-too-many-or-too-few.aspx)
To determine how many VLFs are in teh log run:

```
DBCC LOGINFO
```

You could shrink your Log, but that wouldn't remove the cause of it growing so large in the first place.

The canonical reference is: [8 Steps to better Transaction Log throughput](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/8-Steps-to-better-Transaction-Log-throughput.aspx)

[Note: If your database is NOT a production database, you could set Recovery Mode to Simple.]

[Shrinking the Transaction Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037.aspx)

Comment: If I did backup of database Do I need to clean up log file? it takes space a little bit

Comment: What it is the virtual log file?

Answer (score 0):

a slowly grown log file will create a large number of virtual log files.
this will slow down database startups,restore and backup operations.

to fix this look at this blog: http://www.sqlserveroptimizer.com/2013/02/how-to-speed-up-sql-server-log-file-by-reducing-number-of-virtual-log-file/